# Is there a way to have a Phoenix Plug just for one route?

Tags: routes, elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

In Phoenix I have my routes as follow :

```
  scope "/", ManaWeb do
    pipe_through [:browser, :auth]
    get "/register",  RegistrationController, :new
    post "/register", RegistrationController, :register
  end
```

However I would like to set a Plug for the last route (POST).

How would I go about that with current tools ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it is stated in the documentation for [`Phoenix.Router.pipeline/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#pipeline/2)

> Every time `pipe_through/1` is called, the new pipelines are appended to the ones previously given.

That said, this would work:

```rb
scope "/", ManaWeb do
  pipe_through [:browser, :auth]
  get "/register",  RegistrationController, :new

  pipe_through :post_plug
  post "/register", RegistrationController, :register
end
```

Comment: Keep in mind that any routes you put below your `pipe_through :post_plug` will call the `:post_plug`.

Answer (score 9):

Another solution would be using the plug directly in the controller

```
defmodule ManaWeb.RegistrationController do
  # import the post_plug...
  plug :post_plug when action in [:register]

  def register(conn, params) do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I would say this is more elegant than my proposal. Upvoted.

Comment: The pipeline approach is good enough for me, this is very interesting though as il allows setting the plugs in the controller per route. Is this documented somewhere ?

Comment: @thodg it should be somewhere in the official doc but I read it in the Programming Phoenix book